# How to rearrange text on each line of a file?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with contents of the form

```
LastnameA,FirstnameA
LastnameB,FirstnameB
LastnameC,FirstnameC
LastnameD,FirstnameD    (etc.)
```

I want it to be of the following form:

```
FirstnameA LastnameA
FirstnameB LastnameB
FirstnameC LastnameC
FirstnameD LastnameD    (etc.)
```

Is there a good `awk` or `sed` command to do this?

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their own efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do so now and let us know then.

Answer (score 3):

Split on comma and then print the tokens in reverse like so:

`awk -F, '{print $2, $1}'`